# SQL: require minimum number of input observations for calculation

Tags: sql

I am calculating the variance of variable `var`, grouped by `id` and `year` as follows:

```
SELECT id, year, 
       (AVG(var*var)-AVG(var)*AVG(var)) AS y
FROM table
GROUP BY id, year
```

However, I only want to return variance values which are based on at least 60 observations. How do I achieve this?

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: @TZHX I am using sqlite3 in Python, if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: have a look at the having clause, you should be able to put something like "having count(*) >= 60" in there https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-having/

Comment: Thank you. So simply adding "having count(*) >= 60" at the bottom does the trick?

Comment: yes, I think so -- there might be some tweaks needed for whichever flavour of sqlite you've got but it seems to behave as would be expected. sqlfiddle here demonstrating: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/626ef/1/1